# php get radio button value and pass it to switch

Tags: php, radio-button, switch-statement

My question is how can I get the selected radio button value and pass it into my switch? In other words, how do I define the **myvariable** in switch.

I have the following switch inside my **maincalc.php**:

```
protected function calcCountry(){

        $json = '{my json content for country}';
        return $json;
    }
protected function calcContinent(){

        $json = '{my json content for continent}';
        return $json;
    }
protected function calcCity(){

        $json = '{my json content for city}';
        return $json;
    }

public function mycalculation(){

        switch ($this->myvariable){
            case 'country' :
                $json = $this->calcCountry();
                break;          
            case 'continent' :
                $json = $this->calcContinent();
                break;
            case 'city': 
                $json = $this->calcCity();
                break;
            default : 
                print '<div>Error</div>';
                break;

        }
        writeFile('n.json',$json,'mytool');
        unset($json);
}
```

and here is my form inside my **form.php**:

```
<fieldset id="mytool" >     

            <h2>Please Choose Your Option</h2>
            <div><label ><Input type = 'Radio' Name ='myToolChoice' class='myToolChoice' value= 'country' onClick=''>Country</label></div>
            <div><label ><Input type = 'Radio' Name ='myToolChoice' class='myToolChoice' value= 'continent' onClick=''>Continent</label></div>
            <div><label ><Input type = 'Radio' Name ='myToolChoice' class='myToolChoice' value= 'city' onClick=''>City</label></div>     
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Depends on how you send in the form: `$_GET['myToolChoice']` or `$_POST['myToolChoice']`.

Comment: @jeroen $_POST, i think.

Comment: One advice, you can turn your PhP arrays into json using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are using POST method in your form

```html
<form action="youraction.php" method="POST">
  <input type = 'Radio' Name ='myToolChoice' class='myToolChoice' value= 'country' onClick=''/>Country
  <input type = 'Radio' Name ='myToolChoice' class='myToolChoice' value= 'continent' onClick=''/>Continent
  <input type = 'Radio' Name ='myToolChoice' class='myToolChoice' value= 'city' onClick=''/>City
</form>
```

In youraction.php file

```
<?php
$myVariable = $_POST['myToolChoice'];
//Then you can use it as you want
```

See [POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). 
Here you just send your input via HTML form, and you get it using $_POST.

Note that if you use [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) method in your form, you can get the value in php like `$myVariable = $_GET['myToolChoice']`